# call a Task a second time for side effects

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to write some tests around my plugin https://github.com/fommil/sbt-big-project to assert that unnecessary work is not being performed on invocations of various commands.

However, it seems that it is not possible to invoke a `Task` a second time, even in a [Def.taskDyn](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with). e.g. in the below, nothing happens between "HELLO" and "GOODBYE" as the AST rewrite from the `sbt` macros is obviously just re-using the same reference:

```scala
val testFastCompileTask = Def.taskDyn {
  (compile in Compile).value
  println("HELLO WORLD!")
  Def.task {
    (compile in Compile).value
    println("GOODBYE WORLD!")
  }
}
```

is there any way to force the task to run the second time?

Even creating a dummy task that simply runs `compile`, doesn't invoke the `compile` a second time. I can confirm that in the sbt REPL, typing `compile` a second time **definitely** is doing a bunch of stuff on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, deduplication still occurs since *normally* you don't want compilation to happen twice in this context. You can define your own command or use scripted plugin (as you're now doing) if it's for testing.

Comment: thanks. The testing framework is really good, I should be using that instead anyway.